# Complicated Integral output with Unfamiliar Regularized Hypergeometric Function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I need the solution for following integral and it has output in MATHEMATICA as:

```
FullSimplify[
 Integrate[x^(m - 1) Exp[-a x] Gamma[m, b/x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  Assumptions -> m > 1/2 && a > 0 && b > 0]]
```

[image]

I really do not know the definition of the last  Regularized Hypergeometric Function which has some numbers as superscripts.

Further, does anyone know how we can prove this analytically? Because there is very less integral formulas related to  Regularized Hypergeometric Function.

Further, I found this output somehow numerically unstable for some large $m$.

Example for unstable case:
[image]
[image]

```
testNum[m_, p_, t_] := 
  NIntegrate[
   y^(m - 1) Exp[-((m y)/p)] Gamma[m, (m t)/(p y)], {y, 
    0, \[Infinity]}];
```

`testAny[m_, p_, t_]` can be achieved as

```
FullSimplify[
 Integrate[
  y^(m - 1) Exp[-((m y)/p)] Gamma[m, (m t)/(p y)], {y, 
   0, \[Infinity]}], Assumptions -> m > 1 && p > 0 && t > 0]
```

Comment: If you look at the `FullForm` of the output expression you will see that the superscripts on the `HypergeometricPFQRegularized` represent a derivative with respect to the first numerator parameter.

Comment: What is the  first numerator parameter in this case?

Comment: In `HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{a1,  a2},  {b1,  b2,  b3},  z]` the first set of parameters (`{a1,  a2}`) are numerator parameters, second set (`{b1,  b2,  b3}`) are denominator parameters, and `z` is argument. In your output, the superscript `{{1,0},{0,0,0},0}` -- which denotes differentiation -- maps to these and the `1` indicates the derivative is taken with respect to `a1` and subsequently is evaluated with the parameter value given in the function (`a1` is coincidentally `1` in this specific case). This is analogous to  `f'[1]` which indicates derivative is evaluated for argument at `1`

Comment: What large is `m` ?.What numerical value have: `a,b` ?

Comment: All these can be any general values, However, for simplicity, `m` can be an integer, for numerical purpose lets say `m<10`. `a,b` are real numbers, can be small.

Comment: "Further, I found this output somehow numerically unstable for some large m".What you mean by that ? Please post a code,what have you tried?

Comment: This happens when result is very small values such as `10^(-6)` which can be neglected and I find this is not a big issue for my work. However I still searching how this can be derived analytically.

Comment: I have added one case, it is even for significant value which cannot be neglected.

Comment: Please include copyable code in your question instead of screenshots. It's much more likely to get answers if people don't have to manually type all your definitions by themselves

Comment: The issue is that the terms in the analytical expression nearly cancel each other out (the individual terms are nearly 30 orders of magnitude larger than their sum), causing huge relative numerical errors. You can work around this by increasing the `WorkingPrecision`, e.g. `WorkingPrecision->100` as option to `LogPlot` gives a nice curve.